# How to get entire record by using select clause with distinct in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to fetch entire record with distinct field points so I wrote following query but it is not giving desired result.

```
@top_score_cards = Score.select("DISTINCT points *").order("points DESC , updated_at DESC").where("points != ? And activity_id= ? ",0,params[:@myActivity]).limit(3)
```

It is throwing following error :

> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server versi on for the right syntax to
>   use near 'FROM `scores`  WHERE (points != 0 And activity_id= '1' ) 
>   ORDER BY points DE SC ,' at line 1: SELECT  DISTINCT points * FROM
>   `scores`  WHERE (points != 0 And activity_id= '1' )  ORDER BY poi nts
>   DESC , updated_at DESC LIMIT 3

Comment: shouldn't that be `DISTINCT points` without the *? You either select distinct columns or everything.

Comment: without * it is giving me record with only points but I want entire record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic of what you're asking for doesn't really  make sense, since select will just return the points but you want the whole record.

I think i can guess what it's supposed to be though since i answered another related question earlier.  :)

Am i right in thinking that you want one record for the 3 highest unique "points" value in the table, and when there is more than one record with the same `points` you want the one with the earliest `updated_at`?  if so, then the key to this is `group by`, not select.

```
@top_score_cards = Score.group(:points).order("points DESC , updated_at").where("points <> ? and activity_id = ? ",0,params[:activity_id]).limit(3)
```

I've taken the liberty of fixing lots of syntax errors in your code, so i can't guarantee this this will work or is even what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Then try this instead:

```
Score.where("points != ? And activity_id= ?",0,params[:@myActivity])
  .order("points DESC, updated_at DESC")
  .limit(3)
  .uniq! { |x| x.points }
```

Based on the documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct

Comment: It is also giving following result :   
  
    #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Score id: nil, points: 50>, #<Score id: nil, points: 30>, #<Score id: nil, points: 20
>]>

But I want :

    #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Score id: 12, user_id: 3, activity_id: 1, points: 50, created_at: "2015-06-26 09:34:5
9", updated_at: "2015-06-26 09:34:59">]>

Comment: changed the reply. You need to fetch all objects first then and perform a `uniq!` on the returned collection.